# Shell script If syntax error

Tags: bash, scripts

```
if ($(ipcs|grep test|wc -l)=630); then

echo "Shared Memory check passed"
fi
```

I get below error:

```
./Test1: line 25: 636=630: command not found
```

Answer (score 8):

Some syntax errors

The base for the 'if' constructions in bash is this:

```bsh
if [ expression ];
then
    # code if 'expression' is true.
fi
```

---

here is the corrected version

```bsh
if [ "$(ipcs|grep test|wc -l)" -eq 630 ]; then 
    echo "Shared Memory check passed"
fi
```

or with `[[…]]` to prevents word splitting of variable values without douple quotes

```bsh
if [[ $(ipcs|grep test|wc -l) -eq 630 ]]; then 
    echo "Shared Memory check passed"
fi
```

or better

```bsh
if [[ $(ipcs|grep -c test) -eq 630 ]]; then 
    echo "Shared Memory check passed"
fi
```

Comment: Please excuse the nitpickery, but the `[` is unrelated to the syntax of the `if` statement. The `/usr/bin/[` command and its builtin equivalent `[` are just commands like any other.

Comment: Nevertheless a +1 for relentlessly hammering on the supremacy of `[[` over `[` ;-)

Comment: `$()` doesn't split on space in any case, there's no need to encase it in spaces. In this case. If the output could be empty, then there's need for ""

Answer (score 6):

Essentially there are multiple ways to construct `if` conditionals in `bash`; one is outlined in A.B.'s answer; another one, which is likely the one you are trying to use, involves using double parentheses, which is a way to manipulate expressions / variables in `bash` in a more of a C-style way, and which, per its definition, requires double parentheses in order to work (mind that this won't work e.g. for strings comparisons):

```bsh
if (($(ipcs|grep test|wc -l)==630)); then
    echo "Shared Memory check passed"
fi
```

[More informations on "The Double-Parentheses Construct"](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html)

Comment: this is new for me, thank you and +1

Comment: @A.B. The nicest thing about it is you can do also C-style `for` loops, `while` loops and variables incrementing as you would in C: `for((i=0; i<3; i++)); do [...]; done`, `i=0; while((i<3)); do [...]; done` and `((i++))`. Upvoted yours already obviously

Comment: I'm undereducated :)

Comment: Both upvoted!  When do we see you some time in the chat room?

Comment: @Fabby Thanks :)! Yep it's been some time! Been a little busy lately, gonna join the chat again soon tough because it has been too much time :)

Comment: @canonical This way is likely the one you are trying to go and should be  the accepted answer. ;)

Comment: kos, there is a catch though..this is only suitable for arithmetic operations..

Comment: You forgot a `=`. The correct syntax is `==`

Comment: @heemayl Thanks, I've pointed out that it doesn't work for strings comparisons, however aside from arithmetic and relational operators it seems to work also with logical and bitwise operators so I'm wondering where the limit actually is aside from strings

Answer (score 3):

To add another option: you can do away with square brackets and parentheses altogether by using the `test` built-in instead:

```
if test $(ipcs|grep test|wc -l) -eq 630; then 
    echo "Shared Memory check passed"
fi
```

The `[` built-in essentially is an alias for the `test` built-in, except that it takes one additional argument: `]`.

This also illustrates that the `[` is not part of the the `if` statement. The built-in `[` and binary `/usr/bin/[` are just commands like any other, e.g. `ls` or `grep`.

The `if` statement executes the command(s) between the `if` and the `then`. If the last one has exit code `0`, it executes the commands following the `then`. The `[` command exits with `0` if its arguments -- which it interprets as a logical expression according to certain syntax rules -- evaluate to true.

In fact, you could eliminate the `if` altogether and use only the `[` command, as in the idiomatic:

```
[ $(ipcs|grep test|wc -l) -ne 630 ] || echo "..."
```

Comment: The `630` from the OP became `360` in your answer. Is it a typo?